# Flutter || Add text below AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, appbar, flutter-appbar

There is an application page that is responsible for displaying devices. There is a code that returns AppBar, Body, Drawer.
Question: how do I put the description "List of devices" between AppBar and Body (as in the photo)

[image: sample of output]

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text('IT', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45,
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt,
                             size: 30.0,),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog<Filter>(context: context, builder: (_) {
                return FilterDialog(onApplyFilters: _filter,);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: PhonesList(phones: filteredPhones),

      drawer: Drawer(.....),
            
    );
```

Comment: did you try with "Column" ? It allows you to use widgets vertically, so you can put "List Devices" as widget Text above your phones list

Comment: @swifthing Yes, I tried it, but I caught error. Perhaps I did something wrong. Could you explain to me using my code as an example?

Comment: in this widget "PhonesList", use a Column which contains a widgets array, first widget will be shown at top (for example Text) and, second widget will be shown below the Text that is your phones list. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use appbar bottom ... and customization

```
 bottom: PreferredSize(
             child: Container(
               color: Colors.white,
               child: row(

                ),
             ),
         preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)
      ),
```

Comment: You pointed me to the right way to solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Use `bottom` property of AppBar and add text inside it

Text will be shown at the bottom of AppBar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use a column widget below appbar or introduce a column widget on Body.

```
Column(
          children:<Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color:Colors.green
              ),
              child: Column(
                children:<Widget>[
                     Text("iphone 11 ",style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontSize:25),),
                        Text("ios 15")
                ])
            ),
            Container(
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color:Colors.green
              ),
              child: Column(
                children:<Widget>[
                     Text("iphone 13 ",style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontSize:25),),
                        Text("ios 13")
                ])
            ),
           
          ]
        ),
```